# Conditionally concatenating a list of strings with a condition

Tags: python, string, list, conditional-statements, string-concatenation

I would appreciate suggestions for a more efficient way to conditionally concatenate a list.

This technique seems to work:

```
sentence = ['this ','is ','are ','a ','sentence']
string = ''
for i in sentence:
    if i != 'are ':
        string += i
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
sentence = ['this ','is ','are ','a ','sentence']
string = ''.join([i for i in sentence if i != 'are '])
```

And yes, I used a list comprehension purposefully.  It is [generally faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/2555451) than a generator expression when using `str.join`.

Comment: On my computer the OP's solution is about 5% faster than the list comprehension+join

Answer (score 6):

You can filter out the `are` and concatenate with `"".join`, like this

```
>>> "".join(item for item in sentence if item != "are ")
```

Here, `"".join` means that, join the strings returned by the generator expression with no filling character. If you have `",".join`, then all the elements will be joined by `,`.

Actually, `"".join` will be faster with a list, than with a generator expression. So, just convert the generator expression to a list with list comprehension, like this

```
>>> "".join([item for item in sentence if item != "are "])
```

Comment: I'll have to ask another question on SO about why a list comprehension outperforms a generator here.

Comment: @mattkaeo It is already there. [Answered by one of the Python's core developers, Raymond Hettinger](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/1903116)